# How to move object properties inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
currentArray = [
  {
    year: 2011,
    asset: {
      silver: 322,
      gold: 325,
    },
  },
  {
    year: 2012,
    asset: {
      silver: 411,
      gold: 2235,
    },
  },
];
```

What needs to be done in JavaScript/TypeScript, to change it from the current structure to the structure below? The silver- and gold-property of each asset-object should be stored in the object above, next to 'year', and the asset-objects need to be deleted:

```
desiredArray = [
  {
    year: 2011,
    silver: 322,
    gold: 325,
  },
  {
    year: 2012,
    silver: 411,
    gold: 2235,
  },
];
```

Comment: @felixkling recursion is overkill for this. It just needs a simple map. `const result = currentArray.map(({year, asset}) =>({year, ...asset}));`

Comment: @pilchard, perfect)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let currentArray = [{
    year: 2011,
    asset: {
      silver: 322,
      gold: 325,
    },
  },
  {
    year: 2012,
    asset: {
      silver: 411,
      gold: 2235,
    },
  },
];

currentArray.map(item => {
  Object.assign(item, item.asset)
  delete item.asset;
  
  return item
})

console.log(currentArray)
```

Comment: Even easier: `Object.assign(item, item.asset)`. But if you mutate the array, don't use `.map`.